# What is ipc? How can I use it?

Tags: c#, .net, ipc

What is ipc in .net? Is it possible to use ipc in .net 2003? Please explain how.

Comment: How many marks? A word count limit?

Comment: Read "Operating Systems, design and implementation" by Andrew Tanenbaum

Answer (score 7):

IPC is short for "InterProcess Communication".  It's essentially any method by which 2  processes communicate information.  It is not limited to a particular technology like .Net but is available in many forms.

For the version of the CLR that ships with VS 2003, the most popular IPC mechanism is .Net Remoting.  This is a huge topic and even an introduction is not very easy in an SO post.  Your best bet is to google. for .Net Remoting and start from there.  There are tons of tutorials available

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Remoting
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

IPC stands for Inter-Process Communication.  The possibilities for that in .NET are simply too many to list!  What are you looking for, more precisely?

Comment: "Too many to list" is basically what every tutorial on IPC/sockets/semaphores/mmap say - other than client<->server (e.g. web server <->browser, and similar client/server), what are these things used for? Could you give an example please?

Answer (score 0):

IPC stands for Inter-Process Communication and an example of IPC in ,Net is .Net Remotng. you should google it and try then if you get any problem then do ask in forums.